# Indexed DB: Retrieving a single record as a string

Tags: indexeddb

I am trying to make a function that looks for a single record and returns it as a string.  In the following code, the ALERT works fine, displaying the correct result.  However, I cannot work out how to pass the result to the outer function (read) so I can call it and get a string result.  It keeps coming back "" or undefined, depending on the various solutions I tried. I thought it would be simple but have tried many different ways.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

I know the following code will not work; this is just one of many tries!

```
    function read(itemnumber) {

    var ThisResult ="";
    var transaction = dbInterview.transaction(["ItemNameShort"]);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("ItemNameShort");
    var request = objectStore.get(itemnumber);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
      alert("Unable to retrieve data");
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {

      if(request.result) {
            alert("Name: " + request.result.ItemNameShort);
            ThisResult = JSON.stringify(request.result.ItemNameShort);
      } 
            else {
            alert("Not found"); 
             ThisResult = "";        
      }
       return ThisResult; 
    };

   return ThisResult;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about asynchronous javascript before using indexedDB.

That can be pretty complicated, so, as a shortcut to getting something working, a simple way is to change the code so that instead of returning a value, you pass a function into the function, and then pass the value into the passed in function. For example:

```
function queryByItemNumber(itemnumber, itemHandlerFunction) {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
  openRequest.onupgradeneeded = myUpgradeNeededFunction;
  openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction('ItemNameShort');
    var store = tx.objectStore('ItemNameShort');
    var getRequest = store.get(itemnumber);
    getRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var item = event.target.result;

      // Instead of trying to return item, pass it to the 
      // item handler function
      itemHandlerFunction(item);
    };
  };
} 

// Now, to use the above function, do something like this:
queryByItemNumber(5, function item5HandlerFunction(item) {
  alert(item);
  document.getElementById('asdf').textContent = item.toString();
  console.log('got item %s', item);
  // etc
});
```

Basically, you are moving the code after the call to queryByItemNumber to inside a function you pass to queryByItemNumber. This will work asynchronously. All your code that works with the item must be inside the function item5HandlerFunction (or whatever you want to call it, or leave it without a name, as in an anonymous function). If the code is inside the fn it is guaranteed to only run *after* the item was retrieved. All your code outside the function is not guaranteed to run *after*, even though you write it on a line that is later in your source code file.

Comment: Josh, many thanks for your reply.  I was aware that it involves an AJAX issue as you describe, but I needed the help of someone like you who is more familiar with it.  What I need is to make this particular application run one event at a time, not asynchronously, so I need to make it so that no other events can be triggered before the last one has completed.  Perhaps I should read the entire DB into one or more arrays at the start of the app?

Comment: You can still use an async approach, you just have to write it such that your later actions wait to run until the earlier actions complete. There is no way around it. Reading everything into an in-memory array at the start might work but sounds pretty bad.